# Piping shell script through bash using node.js

Tags: node.js, bash, shell

Say I have this:

```
const cp = require('child_process');

fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/dummy.sh')
  .pipe(cp.spawn('bash').stdin).on('data', d => {
  console.log('data:', d);
});
```

and dummy.sh constains just `echo "this is dummy"`, for whatever reason no data comes through in the on data callback. Does anyone know why that might be? I would expect this output `data: this is dummy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not listening for the output of your *bash* command.
The `on('data')` event handler doesn't trigger your *bash* script output.

Instead, you should listen to the process [stdout](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const cp = require('child_process');

let cmd = cp.spawn('bash');
fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/dummy.sh')
    .pipe(cmd.stdin).pipe(cmd.stdout).on('data', d => {
  console.log('data:', d.toString());  // data: this is dummy
});
```

Comment: yeah I would have just guessed that `.pipe(cmd.stdin)` would return `cmd.stdout`, right?

Comment: No, in itself `pipe()` doesn't invoque the spawned process output. In this case it transmits the `cmd.stdin` output, which logically do not contains anything. To be sure about that, you can try to chain `.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.txt'))` with and without `cmd.stdout`.